# Integrate Beamer (app.getbeamer.com) into Next.js 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm currently working on a Next.js 13 project and would like to integrate Beamer (https://app.getbeamer.com/) to announce updates and new features on my web application.

I've obtained the Beamer script from my Beamer account, but I'm unsure how to integrate it into my Next.js 13 application. I've tried adding it to the `<head>` section of my main layout.tsx file, but the syntax seems to not be supported.

Has anyone successfully implemented Beamer in a Next.js 13 project? If so, could you share your approach or provide guidance on how to properly integrate Beamer with the latest version of Next.js?

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Below is my implementation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With Next.js 13, I managed to integrate Beamer by moving this logic into a Client component and added into the DOM via useEffect. Use that Client component into your RootLayout file.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // Create a new script element
    const scriptElement = document.createElement("script");
    scriptElement.type = "text/javascript";
    scriptElement.defer = true; // or use scriptElement.setAttribute("defer", "true");

    // Add user information to the script content
    scriptElement.innerHTML = `
      var beamer_config = {
        product_id: '<YOUR_BEAMER_PROD_ID>',
        button_position: 'bottom-right',
      };
    `;

    // Append the script element to the document
    document.head.appendChild(scriptElement);

    // Create another script element for the Beamer embed script
    const beamerScriptElement = document.createElement("script");
    beamerScriptElement.type = "text/javascript";
    beamerScriptElement.src = "https://app.getbeamer.com/js/beamer-embed.js";
    beamerScriptElement.defer = true; 

    
    document.head.appendChild(beamerScriptElement);
  }, []);
```